# Google Games: Cloud save game gets deleted by using another flavor

Tags: android, proguard, google-play-games, android-proguard, android-productflavors

I'm experiencing strange errors when using the `Google Play Savegames` and Android `flavors`.
For testing my game, I have two different `flavors`, `dev` for testing and `release` for publishing.

I'm using `Google Play savegames` for both flavors with the same google account. It seems to happen that whenever I push the savegame from one of the versions into the cloud, the other version can't find its savegame any more.

Could there be some kind of conflict by enabling savegame for two `flavors` which could result in the loss of my savegame? Shouldn't this be saved as two different games in the cloud if they have diverging package names (com.company.mygame and com.company.mygame.dev) or how does `Google Play Games` handle this?

Comment: I didn't found any documentation of what is expected or how Google Play Games handle saved games by app with different flavors. You could create a [ticket](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/new) to verify how it is handled and what behavior is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, it was a problem with `Proguard`. `Proguard` renamed the names of my enums which are part of my savegame data, even though the savegamedata itself was excluded from obfuscation. The exclusion worked well for all variable names in the savegame data, but failed for the enum names.

These lines added to the `Proguard` rules fixed the problem:

```
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over JSON, keepclassmembers
-keepclassmembers class com.mycompany.mygame.Utility.SaveGameData** { *; }

# all my enums that were renamed
-keep public enum com.mycompany.mygame.Entities.Player$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}

-keep public enum com.mycompany.mygame.Entities.Enemy$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}

-keep public enum com.mycompany.mygame.Entities.Quest$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}

-keep public enum com.mycompany.mygame.Entities.Room$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```

Comment: Hi Eve. Care to be more specific? More details on what was wrong ang what you changed to make it work might help someone in the future. :) Cheers!

Comment: Hello AL, you're absolutely right, I was so enthusiastic I found a solution that I forgot to give a proper explanation, here it is :)